# Exocortex(Windows 7 Update) seems to interfere with MediaElement

Tags: c#, windows-7, mediaelement

I have a working program that could load and play a video file.  It has a canvas over the video on which an interrupt draws events loaded from a separate text or csv file.  It was all working marvelously and I have been using it for weeks, but I wanted to add fft and video analysis functionality.  I added Exocortex to the project and now loaded videos don't play and loaded events don't display on the canvas.

I can't think of why this would have any effect, and it's the only change that's been made. The rest of the program appears to work normally.  Does Exocortex have anything about it that might interfere with MediaElements or Canvases?

EDIT: Further investigation suggests the problem is not with Exocortex, but with the mediaelement and a recent Windows 7 Update.  The solution is still evading me.

Comment: @Ernest:Thanks, it wouldn't let me add the exocortex tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reformatting my computer with a new install of windows 7 has fixed the problem.  In other words, I have absolutely no idea what was broken and what wasn't working.  Windows Media player was experiencing the same problem.